# Invertibility of Positive Elements in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Let $A$ be unital $C^*$-algebra, and $c$ be a positive element in $A$. Then $a$ is invertible if and only if $a \ge \epsilon 1$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

I think I was able to prove the backward implication. Let $C^(a)$ be the commutative unital $C^*$-subalgebra generated by $a$. By the Gelfand-Naimark theorem, $C^*(a)$ is $*$-isomorphic to the space of continuous functions on some compact topological space; call the isomorphism $\phi$.  If $a \ge \epsilon 1$, then $a - \epsilon 1 \ge 0$ and therefore $\phi (a) - \epsilon > 0$ or $\phi (a) \ge \epsilon$. But this means that $\phi(a)$ is an invertible function, and this inverse can be pulled-back via $\phi$ get furnish an inverse for $a$ itself.

Here is what I have for the forward implication. Suppose that $a$ is invertible. Then because $a$ is invertible *and* positive, and because the spectrum $\sigma (a)$ is nontrivial, there exists $\epsilon \in \sigma (a)$ such that $\epsilon > 0$ and $a - \epsilon 1$ is not invertible...I want to argue that $a - \epsilon 1 \ge 0$, but I don't see how to.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a forward implication instead of contradiction. Since $a$ is invertible then there is a neighborhood of $0\in U\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $a-t1$ is invertible for all $t\in U$. Take $0<\epsilon\in U$. Then $a-\epsilon1$ is invertible. Now, the Gelfand transform $\hat{a}-\epsilon\hat{1}$ is continuous and takes all values $\sigma(a)-\epsilon$. Since $0\notin \sigma(a)-\epsilon$, $\sigma(a)\subset(0,+\infty)$ and $[\epsilon,0]\cap\sigma(a)=\emptyset$, then $\sigma(a)-\epsilon\subset (0,+\infty)$.

Thereofore, $a-\epsilon1\geq0$.

Comment: So you are proving the forward implication via a contradiction. Why can you choose $\epsilon_n > 0$ such that $a - \epsilon_n 1$ is not invertible? The most I can see one concluding is that $a \not\ge \epsilon_n 1$.

Comment: @user193319 Apply the intermediate value theorem to the Gelfand transform $\hat{a}$. If you have $a-\epsilon_n'1\not\geq0$ and $a-0\cdot1>0$, then there is $\epsilon_n$ such that $a-\epsilon_n$ is not invertible. The continuous function $t\mapsto \hat{a}-t\hat{1}$ takes some non-positive value at $t=\epsilon_n'$ and positive values at $t=0$.

Comment: @user193319 Reworded the argument into a direct one, instead of by contradiction, and gave more details. Maybe that way it is more understandable.